# Optimizing MKAnnotationView Performance with drop shadows and motion effects

Tags: optimization, ios7, core-graphics, mapkit, mkannotationview

So in my mapView I've presently use custom mapPins (instances of MKAnnotationView) whose main appearance consists of three aspects:

1) setting each mapPin.image to one of three core images (partially translucent png)

2) possibly adding a second image (a partially translucent png) as a subview of each mapPin

3) possibly adding a third image (a partially translucent png) as another subview of each mapPin

Then I add a drop shadow layer.

Last I add four motion effects, two to the drop shadow and two to the pin (so they float on the map, it looks really cool).

Of course this is resulting in FPS drops when lots of these are present.

BTW when these mapPins get re-used, I do clear out the subviews before readding them, and I do not add more drop shadow layers if there already is one.

I am trying to optimize this. For one thing, the png's alias on the retina display and I want them to be at native res. How? I'm not scaling them as it is; I don't know why they're misaligned. Also, the images are just colored circles; I feel like I should be able to draw them on the fly to a dynamic CG bitmap context using CG arcs, but would that yield an FPS boost? Can I merge the 3 pngs somehow into one image?

Thanks. I'm kinda new to CoreGraphics and optimizing performance. I am looking at my app and it doesn't *look* like I'm doing anything fancy that would be tanking the FPS. That's why I'm not sure what to do to fix it.